# Jquery basic form validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to create my own basic form validation without having to resort to heavy, one-size-fits-all plugins and I have written the following code. It doesn't seem to matter how often I rewrite it and start over, I can't seem to get it to work.

The idea is that the script checks the form to see if all the fields have been completed and if so it removes the disabled attribute from the submit button.

The Function:-

```
function checkForm(){
$('#contact :input').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('value') == null){
     var checked = false; 
    } else {
     var checked = true;
    }
})
if (checked == true){
   alert('all filled in');
   //remove disabled attribute from button  
} else {
    alert('not completed');
    //add disabled attribute to button
}

}
```

And the code that calls the function:-

```
$('#contact :input').blur(function(){
     if ($(this).val() <= ''){
        $(this).next('.error').show();
    } else {
        $(this).next('.error').hide();
        checkForm();
    }
})
```

I've been messing about with this all day and am struggling to find an answer via Google.

Comment: There might be an issue with the way you are comparing `if ($(this).val() <= ''){ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkForm(){
  var checked = true;
  $('#contact :input').each(function(){
    if(!$.trim($(this).val()).length) checked = false;
  })
  if (checked){
   alert('all filled in');
   //remove disabled attribute from button  
  } else {
    alert('not completed');
    //add disabled attribute to button
  }
}
```

And to call the function

```
$('#contact :input').on('blur', function(){
     if (!$.trim($(this).val()).length){
        $(this).next('.error').show();
    } else {
        $(this).next('.error').hide();
        checkForm();
    }
})
```

Comment: Darn it, I did 'if(checked)' earlier :) - This example seems to be doing what I need it to do - thanks for cutting the code down.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're creating the 'checked' variable inside the anonymous function of the .each(), the checked variable is not available outside of that function for your if(checked == true) test (you get a 'checked is undefined' error) which is why your alerts aren't firing.

Try first defining the 'checked' variable outside of the anonymous function and then updating it accordingly.

```
function checkForm() {

    var checked = true;

    $('#contact :input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            checked = false;
        }
    })

    if (checked == true) {
        alert('all filled in');
        //remove disabled attribute from button  
    } else {
        alert('not completed');
        //add disabled attribute to button
    }

}

$('#contact :input').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).next('.error').show();
    } else {
        $(this).next('.error').hide();
        checkForm();
    }
})
```

Here's a jsFiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/DMLzK/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery.validate() function for this and its reference URL is : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0):

correction :

```
function checkForm(){
$('#contact :input').each(function(){
 if($(this).val() == ''){
    var checked = false; 
  } else {
 var checked = true;
}
})
if (checked == true){
 alert('all filled in');
 //remove disabled attribute from button  
 } else {
alert('not completed');
//add disabled attribute to button
 }

}
```

and

```
$('#contact :input').blur(function(){
 if ($(this).val() == ''){
    $(this).next('.error').show();
} else {
    $(this).next('.error').hide();
    checkForm();
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm pretty sure I did try this approach before but I've just tried it again and it's still not triggering any of the alerts at the bottom of the function

Comment: then add alert on $(this).val() to check that what value you are getting and what u want to get.

Comment: also check what value you are getting for `checked` field